# Code exit status 255

Tags: python

I have written the below code for getting the only unique element in a given integer array.

```
def lonelyinteger(a):
    for x in a:
        answer = a.count(x)
        if(a.count(x) < 2)
            answer=x
    return answer
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = input()
    b = map(int, raw_input().strip().split(" "))
    print lonelyinteger(b)
```

**Error**

> File "solution.py", line 5
>       if(a.count(x) < 2)
>                        ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> Exit Status
>   255

Please tell me where did I miss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `:` at the end of that line.

Comment: Ohh shoot, Thanks a Lot

Answer (score -1):

Correct code below this (your code modified):

```
def lonelyinteger(a):
    # added a : that was missing in the for
    # loop (syntax error)
    for x in a:
        answer = a.count(x)
        if(a.count(x) < 2):
            answer=x
    return answer
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = input()
    b = map(int, raw_input().strip().split(" "))
    print lonelyinteger(b)
```

Comment: Why was this answer down voted? Its just a modification of the code to make it correct.

Comment: Perhaps because this answer needlessly reposts a bunch of code with the correction hidden somewhere inside it, and doesn't explain what the problem was.

Comment: @khelwood, just corrected it, thats for telling me.